# How to return an array for OPenCV OutputArray in stead of a one dimensional matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-mat, python

I am making a change to my OpenCV-python project and I have a function that outputs some data using a CV::OutputArray as follows:

```
bool myFunction(cv::OutputArray myOutputArray)
{
    //get some data for output..blah blah

    cv::Mat(1, dataLength, CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, 1), data).copyTo(myOutputArray);
}
```

When I view the contents of myOutputArray in my debugger I see that its a one dimensional ndarray as follows:
[image]

So for me to access each element I need to do e.g:

```
    first_number = my_data[0][0]
    second_number = my_data[0][1]
    third_number = my_data[0][2]
    and so on and so on
```

How can I mofidy my code so that its just a plain array thats returned?
So I can access the data simply as follows:

```
    first_number = my_data[0]
    second_number = my_data[1]
    third_number = my_data[3]
```

Comment: how do you write your C++ code so it's accessible from python? you as a user are *not* supposed to use `OutputArray` in your code at all. those things are a consequence of some design decisions within OpenCV. in C++ it is supposed to be a cv::Mat or maybe a std::vector of things. in python, a cv::Mat is mapped to a numpy array. the shape is always (height, width, numchannels).

Comment: I am actually modifying OpenCV to pass out some custom data, so I have to use it.

Comment: anyway, there's no mechanism within OpenCV and its python bindings that would allow to return python lists, or numpy arrays that have any other shape than 3-dimensional (height, width, channels). just stick with the numpy arrays that are mapped from cv::Mat